# Query (SQL type) on JSON

Tags: sql, json, razor

I have this code that extracts the fields from JSON:

```
@{
var strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Prod ORDER BY IdSpec ASC, NameSpec ASC";

var db = Database.Open(App.connDatabase);
var data = db.Query(strQuery);
var json = Json.Encode(data);
Response.Write(json);


var DecodifEsJson = Json.Decode(json);

foreach (var decod in DecodifEsJson)
{

    <p>
        <strong>@decod.IdSpec</strong><br />
        @decod.NameSpec<br />
    </p>
}
```

}

JSon code output:

```
[{"IdSpec":1,"IdSpecPar":null,"NameSpec":"Spec"},{"IdSpec":10,"IdSpecPar":0,"NameSpec":"BiClassif"},{"IdSpec":4,"IdSpecPar":0,"NameSpec":"BiCol"},{"IdSpec":2,"IdSpecPar":0,"NameSpec":"St"},{"IdSpec":3,"IdSpecPar":2,"NameSpec":"36 m "},{"IdSpec":6,"IdSpecPar":4,"NameSpec":"Bi"},{"IdSpec":5,"IdSpecPar":4,"NameSpec":"Ro"},{"IdSpec":8,"IdSpecPar":4,"NameSpec":"Sc"},{"IdSpec":11,"IdSpecPar":10,"NameSpec":"Ab"}]
```

Question: is there a way to apply the query, similar to SQL to "filter" JSON?

For example:

Only select all fields with "IdSpecPar" = 0:

```
[{"IdSpec":10,"IdSpecPar":0,"NameSpec":"BiClassif"},{"IdSpec":4,"IdSpecPar":0,"NameSpec":"BiCol"},{"IdSpec":2,"IdSpecPar":0,"NameSpec":"St"}]
```

etc...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

DeSerialize the json to a collection class and use LINQ to query the desired result.:

```
/*create the class in Model*/

     public class jObject
        {
          public string IdSpecPar { get; set; }
          public int IdSpec { get; set; }
          public string NameSpec { get; set; }
        }

/* view */    
 @{
      var strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Prod ORDER BY IdSpec ASC, NameSpec ASC";

      var db = Database.Open(App.connDatabase);
      var data = db.Query(strQuery);
      var json = Json.Encode(data);

      var jsonColl = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jObject>>(json);
      var result = from r in jsonColl
                   where r.IdSpec == 0
                   select r;


      foreach (var item in result)
      {

      <p>
        <strong>@item.IdSpec</strong><br />
        @item.NameSpec<br />
      </p>
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hello JBaby and thanks for your interest!

Can you, please, give me an example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example. Please let me know if any further queries.

Comment: It is not possible do everything in Razor? Without "Get / set"?

Comment: If ur using MVC , create the class object in the model. Deserialization & LinQ can be written in the view too using server tags.

Comment: Forgive me,
but I can not convert it to razor.

How should I do?

Comment: I will need more details on the error your getting. What do you mean cannot convert into razor ? Did you create the class object ? also did you copy pasted the "view" code to your razor view i.e .cshtml file. Please provide more details on how are you implementing the code.

Comment: If our getting an error due to the missing reference for Newtonsoft.Json , please install the package to your project . Refer :https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add a class to contain the JSON

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int IdSpec { get; set; }
    public int IdSpecPar { get; set; }
    public string NameSpec { get; set; }
}
```

Now serialize like this.

```
var json = Json.Encode(data);
var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = ser.Deserialize<List<SomeClass>>(json);
```